# In two articles first author and year is same difference co-authors in same publication year in overleaf project

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, apacite, authoryear

For my project in Overleaf using `\bibliographystyle(apacite)` and `.bib file`, when two articles have the same first author and publication year. The difference is in the names of co-authors. I am getting in-text citation in author-year format something like this:
(X,Y,Z, et al., 2000) and (X, Y, P, et al.,2000).
However, I am expecting something like this (X et al.,2000a) and (X et al.,2000b).

Any package or preamble to do it?
Please help.

Comment: This is correct APA style (6th edition) https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/12/how-to-cite-different-groups-of-authors-with-the-same-lead-author-and-publication-date.html. Since `apacite` implements 6th-edition APA style, this is expected behaviour. Off the top of my head I don't know how easy it is to suppress this, but if you don't want APA style behaviour it might be better to use a different style altogether. (If you want APA style keep in mind that `apacite` only implements 6th-editiona APA style, but the current edition is the seventh.)

Comment: @moewe thank you. After reading referred blog what I understood is the results I am getting the correct approach to handle such situations.